# How to draw the stroke behind bars in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've wrote a custom Bar Chart in Chart.JS which on dataset hover highlight the bars by drawing a stroke on it the issue is that stroke is drawn over bars while i would make it something like 'background color' instead.

[image]

Like the bars are visible because the stroke color opacity is set to 0.05 while if i set it to 1 obviously those will not be visible anymore.

The code

```
class CustomBar extends Chart.BarController {
    draw() {
        super.draw(arguments);
        if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
            const points = this.chart.tooltip._active[0];
            const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
            const x = points.element.x;
            const topY = points.element.y + 150;
            const width = points.element.width;
            const bottomY = 0;

            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, topY * 100);
            ctx.lineTo(x + width * 1.3, bottomY);
            ctx.lineWidth = width * 4.3;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
}

CustomBar.id = 'shadowBar';
CustomBar.defaults = Chart.BarController.defaults;

Chart.register(CustomBar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a custom plugin for this, in there you can specify that you want it to draw before the datasets are being drawn. You can do that like so:

```js
Chart.register({
  id: 'barShadow',
  beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      ctx,
      tooltip,
      chartArea: {
        bottom
      }
    } = chart;
    
    if (!tooltip || !tooltip._active[0]) {
      return
    }
    
    const point = tooltip._active[0];
    const element = point.element;
    const x = element.x;
    const topY = -(element.height + 150);
    const width = element.width;
    const bottomY = 0;
    const xOffset = opts.xOffset || 0;
    const shadowColor = opts.color || 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = shadowColor;
    ctx.fillRect(x - (element.width / 2) + xOffset, bottom, width * 1.3 * 4.3, topY);
    ctx.restore();
  }
});

const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      barShadow: {
        xOffset: -10,
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably i will need to create a new question but i will try to make it here:
Is there a way to stuck that stroke on click? I need to make the datasets clickable and understand when one of them is selected the hover helps but it would be cool if on click the stroke would persist, could you guide me in that?

Comment: You could add your own variable to the chart instance and save the last point in there if if you clicked the bar (with afterEvent listener), and then in the render before render you check first if that variable contains a point if so use that otherwise do current logic

Comment: I have one more issue, my dataset is dynamic and setting the stroke width with * 1.3 * 4.3 just break the view when there are more or less datasets, can i get the width by calculating it like with the  distance  of the two datasets elements?